# Neither example uploads to sage server: There was an error uploading the worksheet. It could be an old unsupported format or worse.

Tags: sage

There plenty of "examples" on Sage page http://wiki.sagemath.org/days13/projects/sagenewbie?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=primer_template_example.sws

Unfortunately, they are not loaded into Sage with error message

> There was an error uploading the worksheet. It could be an old
>   unsupported format or worse. If you desperately need its contents
>   contact the sage-support group and post a link to your worksheet.
>   Alternatively, an sws file is just a bzip2 tarball; take a look
>   inside! Return to Upload File.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

These are indeed "old unsupported format"s, from 2009, long before the current versions.  However, as noted, you can just look inside the file.  Try going to your command line and doing

```
$ tar -xjvf my_file.sws
```

and it should spit out a directory which includes a `worksheet.html`; you can then upload that directly into the Sage notebook, I believe.

Comment: As a postscript, I should point out that there are far better primers probably available now; see the Sage website for links, notably http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~mosulliv/Teaching/sdsu-sage-tutorial/index.html and http://www.sagemath.org/doc/prep/index.html